# Select query with GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

i have two tables look like that.

**users**

```
id       name
10       dani
 9       mark
 8       himel
 7       dipu
```

**config_project**

```
id    assignee_web  assignee_app  assignee_qa
29       10,7,9       10,7          10,9
28        10,8       9,10,7          8
```

here, **assignee_web**, **assignee_app** and **assignee_qa** all are the reference id with **id** of **users** table. now i want a select query which output will look like

```
id    assignee_web         assignee_app          assignee_qa
29   dani,dipu,mark         dani, dipu            dani,mark
28     dani,himel           dani,mark,dipu         himel
```

i have wriiten a query which displays only assignee_web. here is my code

```
SELECT c.id as id, GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ', ') as assignee_web FROM config_project c, users u
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, c.assignee_web)
        GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

I  can get only assignee_web data but can't return data for assignee_app and assignee_qa with this query.

Comment: Normalize your tables. Period.

Comment: what results are you getting now?

Comment: and any of your other questions solved? or are they still open/unsolved?

Comment: @Fred- i can get only assignee_web data but can't return data for assignee_app and assignee_qa with this query

Comment: future readers to this and your other questions that were solved may think they're not solved and be tempted to post more answer. Accepting them marks them as solved. They get rewarded for their grace and you gain more rep ;-) it's a "win-win"

Comment: i have less reputation that's why i can't vote an answer. what can i do now??

Comment: Just normalise your schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use correlated queries:

```
SELECT c.id as id,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM users u
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, c.assignee_web)) as assignee_web,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM users u
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, c.assignee_app)) as assignee_app,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.name SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM users u
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.id, c.assignee_qa)) as assignee_qa                
FROM config_project c
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

Though you should normalize your data. People just never learn, and each time you are having some new problems, and you will keep on having them.

Comment: i should mark the answer but i have less reputation that's why i can't vote or mark an answer. in this case what can i do now? i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: @user7149801 You don't have the reputation to vote yet, but you can still accept answers by marking the (V) sign on the left to the answer. You just have to wait 15 minutes since the time you opened the post :)

Comment: Ooh, minus one for something so hideous. :-(

Comment: You didn't actually 'minused' my answer:) I never said it's pretty, I just assumed he needs a disposable query for a one time usage ; Not everything needs to be pretty ..